# nHibernate Distinct query

Tags: nhibernate

Code

IList VendorList;

```
                VendorList = session
                    .CreateCriteria<VendorLookup>()
                    .Add(Expression.Eq("NetworkRunId", networkRunId))
                    .Add(Expression.Not(Expression.Eq("VendorName", " ")))  
                    .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                    .AddOrder(new Order("VendorName", true))
                    .List<IVendorLookup>().Distinct<IVendorLookup>().ToList();
```

Generated Query Please help me out

```
SELECT   this_.Sp    as HCO1_25_0_,
         this_.NID  as Network2_25_0_,
         this_.Vname as HCO3_25_0_
FROM     HCO_V_Lookup this_
WHERE    this_.NID = 5 /* @p0 */
         and not (this_.VNAME = ' ' /* @p1 */)
ORDER BY this_.VNAME asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person));
criteria.SetProjection(
    Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("FirstName"), "FirstName"))
        .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("LastName"), "LastName"))));

criteria.SetResultTransformer(
    new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Person)));

IList people = criteria.List();
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're wondering why the `DISTINCT` doesn't appear in the SQL. It's because it's applied in your criteria query as a result transformer - the SQL query results are filtered to make them distinct after the query has been run.

Comment: i changed my code and now i am able tro see the distinct in the query
added this

.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property("NetworkRunId")).Add(Projections.Property("VendorName"))))

removed
 .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()

i am getting an exception

ERROR: 
The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "Common.Interface.Domain.Common.IVendorLookup" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value

Comment: i found the issue is when the query is generated with DISTINCT i am getting exception.

Comment: if i use this i am getting only one result set
crit.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to make it clearer. I can't read all your comments above, as they extend under a list on the right hand side of the screen.